# Jquery infinite scroll plugin - custom loader

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm using the following infinite scroll plugin.

https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll

The loading start function though, doesn't seem to be working. If I add it, then infinitescroll never loads the next set up images. If I remove it, it then works fine. My main goad, is trying to use another loader, more specifically: Canvas Loader http://heartcode.robertpataki.com/canvasloader/

Here's the code that works just fine:

```
loading: {
    msgText: '<em>Loading more looks</em><div class="lines"><span></span><span></span></div>',
    finishedMsg: "That's all we got!",
    img: '/static/img/logo.png',
    speed: 'fast',
    finished: function() {
        console.log('Finished');
    }
},
```

Here's the code that isn't working:

```
loading: {
    msgText: '<em>Loading more looks</em><div class="lines"><span></span><span></span></div>',
    finishedMsg: "That's all we got!",
    img: '/static/img/logo.png',
    speed: 'fast',
    start: function() {
        console.log('Start Loading');
    },
    finished: function() {
        console.log('Finished');
    }
```

},

Anyone know if it's possible to use another loader rather than just an animated gif.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the `img` option to the new image path. Download the loader image and save it somewhere and give the path in `img`.

```
loading: {
    msgText: '<em>Loading more looks</em><div class="lines"><span></span><span></span></div>',
    finishedMsg: "That's all we got!",
    img: '<path_to_your_new_loader_img>',
    speed: 'fast',
    finished: function() {
        console.log('Finished');
    }
},
```

Comment: Will this plugin only use a img as a loader then? I was trying to get to use an external loader.

Comment: Seems like it supports only images. You can get loader images from http://ajaxload.info/